# Is there a limit to how hot an object can be?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

We know that speed of physical object cant exceed speed of light, a body cant be cooler than 0k, thus does there exist a limit to hotness of an object?

Comment: Melting temperature?

Comment: No, just the overall temperature, be it temperature in its gaseous phase.

Comment: In that case, we are not talking about "a body" or "an object" anymore but merely the temperature of an atom. And when the atoms are heated to the plasma state, even they split into smaller parts and we are not talking about atoms anymore either. And so on.